# Which one is better to work with, vector or arraylist?

Tags: java, oop, netbeans

I have to do a program using arrays of objects to make a person type object that receives ID, name, gender ... etc.  which is better to use arraylist or vectors?

Comment: `ArrayList` - `Vector` is ancient.

Comment: Always search Stack Overflow thoroughly before posting.

Comment: @BasilBourque yes my bad srry, I'm new on stackoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ArrayList` is better (with `Collections.synchronizedList` if you need a thread-safe list, which I doubt you do). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386275/why-is-java-vector-and-stack-class-considered-obsolete-or-deprecated).